# Repeatedly Writing to a File

Tags: java, file

I'm a moderately-experienced C++ guy slowly learning Java.  I'm writing a program which needs to do the following:

- Create a simple text file, default directory is fine
- As the program runs, periodically write one line of data to the file.  Depending on a number of factors, the program may write to the file once or a million times.  There is no way of knowing which write will be the last.

I've been researching different ways to do this, and this is the working code I've come up with.  There are two files, "PeteProgram.java" and "PeteFileMgr.java" :

```
/*
"PeteProgram.java"
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class PeteProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String PeteFilename="MyRecordsFile.txt";
      Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(PeteFilename), "utf-8"));
      PeteFileMgr MyPeteFileMgr = new PeteFileMgr(writer);

      MyPeteFileMgr.AddThisString(writer, "Add this line #1\n");
      MyPeteFileMgr.AddThisString(writer, "Add this line #2\n");
      MyPeteFileMgr.AddThisString(writer, "Add this line #3\n");

    }
}


//=====================================================================================================
//=====================================================================================================


/*
"PeteFileMgr.java"
*/

import java.io.*;

public class PeteFileMgr {

  public PeteFileMgr(Writer writer) {

       try {
          writer.write("File created!");

             } catch (IOException ex) {
          // report
          } finally {
             try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
          }
      }

  void AddThisString(Writer writer, String AddThis) {

    try {
          writer.append(AddThis);

             } catch (IOException ex) {
          // report
          } finally {
             try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
          }
      } 
  }
```

The initial creation of the file works just fine.  However, the to-be-added lines are not written into the file.  Because the program compiles and runs with no errors, I assume the program tries to write the added lines, fails, and throws an exception.  (Unfortunately, I am working with a primitive compiler/debugger and can't see if this is the case.)

Does anyone spot my mistake?

```
       Many thanks!
            -P
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're not flushing the `Writer`. You should call `flush` from time to time. Also, you should `close` your `Writer` **at the end of your app**, not after writing content into it. `close` method automatically flushes the contents of the writer.

So, this is how your code should look like:

```
public class PeteProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String peteFilename = "MyRecordsFile.txt";
        //here's when the physical file is created
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(peteFilename), "utf-8"));
        PeteFileMgr peteFileMgr = new PeteFileMgr(writer);

        peteFileMgr.addThisString(writer, "Add this line #1\n");
        peteFileMgr.addThisString(writer, "Add this line #2\n");
        peteFileMgr.addThisString(writer, "Add this line #3\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle the exception
            //basic handling
            e.printStacktrace();
        } finally {
            //this is a must!
            try { writer.close(); } catch(IOException silent) { }
        }
    }
}

public class PeteFileMgr {
    public PeteFileMgr(Writer writer) {
        try {
            //this method is not creating the physical file
            writer.write("File created!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          // report
        } finally {
            //remove this call to close
            //try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }

    public void addThisString(Writer writer, String addThis) {
        try {
            writer.append(addThis);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // report
        } finally {
            //remove this call to close
            //try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Or if using Java 7 or superior using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
public class PeteProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String peteFilename = "MyRecordsFile.txt";
        //here's when the physical file is created
        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(peteFilename), "utf-8"))) {
        PeteFileMgr peteFileMgr = new PeteFileMgr(writer);

        peteFileMgr.addThisString(writer, "Add this line #1\n");
        peteFileMgr.addThisString(writer, "Add this line #2\n");
        peteFileMgr.addThisString(writer, "Add this line #3\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle the exception
            //basic handling
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The call to `writer.close()` should still be in a `finally` block in `main`.